# Help me figure out this love note!

Tags: story, cipher

I am getting married soon, and wanted to do something special for my fiancée. I wrote her a short love note and sent it to her in the mail.

Today, I opened a letter from her that stated the following:

> pjktjkwgmlcxhfxt
>   xmlgwlipmdilzxff
>   pmiftntjoxoftdcx

What is my fiancée trying to tell me?

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the letter you wrote to her?

Comment: @JustWondering - It's her response to my letter.

Comment: Could you post your letter?

Comment: I guess you'll find out on your wedding night!

Comment: I just noticed that the envelope has a drawing of a picket fence on it, with three vertical boards. I wonder if that is a hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is

> We will say our 'i do's and you will have my heart forever more.

Reasoning

> First (as suggested by the hint in the comments about the picket fence with **three** vertical boards), transpose the three horizontal rows of characters to yield three vertical columns like so 
>  pxp
> jmm
> kli
> tgf
> jwt
> kln
> wit
> gpj
> mmo
> ldx
> cio
> xlf
> hzt
> fxd
> xfc
> tfx 
>  Then read this as a single line of text 
>  pxpjmmklitgfjwtklnwitgpjmmoldxcioxlfhztfxdxfctfx 
>  Then employ decryption via a substitution cipher to the resulting line of text with the following substitutions (i.e, replace the letter in the top line with the letter directly below it) 
>  | a | b | c | d | e | f | g |h | i | j | k | l |m| n | o | p | q | r | s | t | u | v | w | x | y |z | 
>  | b | c |m | v | g | r | u | t |y | i | s |a | l | n | h | w | j | k | p |o | q | x | d | e | z | f | 
>  and the resulting text is 
>  wewillsayouridosandyouwillhavemyheartforevermore 
>  which becomes the answer after adding spaces and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is a little late, and that the message might not be of any importance now, but here is what i have come to (and I'm sad to say it's not much):

The format that the text is in is 16 characters on each line, we can make one assumption...

> The Cipher **could** be contained within a 4x4 grid, and in that case would most likely be a [Route Cipher.](http://crypto.interactive-maths.com/route-cipher.html)

But we cannot get anywhere without a **Key**.

The encrypted text you have given does use several uses of the letter "J" which does not make any sense, because often "J" and "I" are substituted for one another and the "I" is most commonly used when it is substituted.

This means that either your Fiancée is either very clever or it is not a Route Cipher. This would be much easier with a key of some sorts, but without the text is pretty much useless.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Unfortunately, this answer does not attempt to answer the question.  Once you have gained more reputation, you will be able to comment on the question instead.

Comment: It seems rather unlikely that this is a route cipher because there are so few vowels in the given text.